# implement SEO code inside every page head tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I need to index multiple versions of a pages for different languages or regions such that Google Search point users to the most appropriate version of our page by language or region on a ASP.NET project pages which is on top of Sitefinity.

As per the Google Documentation in order to achieve this i need to include below html code on our HTML head tag.

`<'link rel="alternate" hreflang="lang_code" href="url_of_page" />`

E.g.
For below ABC Page we are have multiple language version as mention below and we are using English as a default language so to index this page on Google search we needed to append below code in Head tag:

```
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    ABC
    </TITLE>
    <link rel=alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.NNN.co/de/ABC" />
    <link rel=alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.NNN.co/fr/ABC" />
    <link rel=alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.NNN.co/en/ABC" />
    </HEAD>
```

So in order to achieve this I have used below code on Global.asax.cs file.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           _log.Info("Application starting.");

           ObjectFactory.Initialized += ObjectFactoryInitialized;
           Bootstrapper.Initialized += Bootstrapper_Initialized;
           Bootstrapper.Initialized += BootstrapperInitialized;
           
           // NOTE: Telerik | use this event as a later one compared to the Bootstrapper_Initialized
           Bootstrapper.Bootstrapped += BootstrapperBootstrapped;
           MiniProfiler.Settings.PopupRenderPosition = RenderPosition.Right;
           ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                      SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

           RegisterBundlingContexts();
       }

       private void Bootstrapper_Initialized(object sender, Telerik.Sitefinity.Data.ExecutedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (e.CommandName == "Bootstrapped")
           {
               EventHub.Subscribe<IPagePreRenderCompleteEvent>(this.OnPagePreRenderCompleteEventHandler);
           }
       }

       private void OnPagePreRenderCompleteEventHandler(IPagePreRenderCompleteEvent @event)
       {
           var page = @event.Page;
           //CultureInfo DefaultCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;

           var siteDefaultCulture = SystemManager.CurrentContext.CurrentSite.DefaultCulture ;
           var pageSiteNode = SiteMapBase.GetActualCurrentNode();
           var pageManager = PageManager.GetManager();

           var pageNode = pageManager.GetPageNode(pageSiteNode.Id);
           var publishedTranslations = pageNode.GetPageData().PublishedTranslations;

           var googleLinks = new StringBuilder();
           foreach (var culture in publishedTranslations)
           {
               var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
               string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(pageNode.GetFullUrl(cultureInfo, false, true));
               googleLinks.AppendLine($@"<link rel=""alternate"" hreflang=""{culture}"" href=""{url}"" />");
           }

           googleLinks.Replace($@"hreflang=""{siteDefaultCulture}""", $@"hreflang=""x-default""");

           
           page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(googleLinks.ToString()));

       }
```

but some how its not working and I already have invested huge amount of time using this approach so is there any simpler way to do this.

Note: we are having 100+ pages and each page is having multiple language version

Comment: what exactly is not working? what is the outcome?

Comment: Above code should insert    ` <link rel=alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.NNN.co/de/ABC" />
    <link rel=alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.NNN.co/fr/ABC" />
    <link rel=alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="http://www.NNN.co/en/ABC" />` in the head tag of every page (if it work) but im not getting this output

Comment: Ok, so if you debug where does it fail? Does it properly create the string googleLinks? If so, does it add it to the page Header?